# Want to list all the existing columns in the table as output of one stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I have one UI where user will select one table name depending on it next drop down will get updated.
I want some way by which I can manage the second drop down and list all the columns present in that select table.(I know this could be risk and can be more simpler then I thought).

Comment: totally u have how many dropdowns

Comment: two one for table selection one for column

Comment: so first dropdown is to select the table.on its index changing you want all the columns of particular table to be loaded in second dropdown.

Comment: Yes,on index change second dropdown should list all the related columns

Comment: SELECT column_name
FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name = dropdownlist1.selectedvalue.tostring(). Put this in ur index change event..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say for Example:

```
    protected void DropDown2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    // do all connection things.
    query="select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where
           TABLE_NAME="+DropDown1.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }
```

write this in second dropdown and the table name is selected in dropdown1

Comment: you are writing this code in DropDown1_SelectedIndexChanged sure ?